# Sobre o atributo booleano defer e async vs otimização

Tags: html5, async, defer

O uso de `async` e `defer` para otimização é um bom assunto a tocarmos quando queremos páginas carregadas de forma mais rápida e também sem problemas de bloqueamento.

Dúvidas:

- Usando `async`, se o navegador não der suporte, ele ignora o atributo
  e baixa/executa o script normalmente, ou ele simplesmente o ignora, não carregando-o?
- Considerando que o objetivo do `async` e do `defer`, é realizar o carregamento dos scripts sem interromper/bloquear a renderização da página, não seria a mesma coisa que coloca-los(os
  scripts) antes do `</body>`? Ou por carregar assincronamente, ele é mais rápido já que não depende que a renderização seja concluída?
- As bibliotecas para carregamento assíncrono, como o **LABjs**, ainda
  são úteis, tendo em vista estes atributos(`async/defer`)? Ou eles são
  de certa maneira mais seguros, garantindo o carregamento assíncrono
  independendo da versão do navegador?
- Considerando que o `defer` permite que o script seja carregado de
  forma assíncrona, mas só permite sua execução após a renderização,
  ele pode ser melhor que o `async`, já que este executa após o
  carregamento, mesmo que ainda esteja ocorrendo a renderização?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Usando `async`, se o navegador não der suporte, ele ignora o atributo
>   e baixa/executa o script normalmente, ou ele simplesmente o ignora,
>   não carregando-o?

Ele ignora somente o atributo, o script é baixado normalmente como se não houvesse `defer` ou `async`, isto é, bloqueando o *parse* da página. Você pode verificar melhor quais navegadores suportam esses atributo por meio dos links: [async](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async) e [defer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer).

O `async` é um atributo novo já o `defer`, se não me engano foi implementado pela Microsoft há muito tempo e então os demais navegadores passaram a dar suporte nas versões mais novas. Você pode usar a técnica de combinar os dois atributos para impedir o bloqueio da renderização e continuar baixando os scripts em segundo plano:

```
<script src='meuscript-js' async defer></script>
```

Se o navegador do usuário suportar ambos os atributos, `async` prevalecerá. Caso não suporte `async`, o atributo será ignorado e então `defer` será utilizado. **Importante**: A ordem de execução após o download é diferente e será explicada na próxima pergunta.

> Considerando que o objetivo do `async` e do `defer`, é realizar o
>   carregamento dos scripts sem interromper/bloquear a renderização da
>   página, não seria a mesma coisa que coloca-los (os scripts) antes do
>   `</body>`? Ou por carregar assincronamente, ele é mais rápido já que não
>   depende que a renderização seja concluída?

Não deve levar em consideração somente o "carregar assincronamente", vale ressaltar que cada atributo tem um comportamento e serve para um propósito.

[image: Execução]
<sup>[Referência](http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/)</sup>

`async` deve ser usado para `scripts` que podem ser executados independente do documento estar pronto ou não. O script será baixado sem interromper o *parse* da página e executado logo em seguida. No link de referência acima, um exemplo que bem simples para ilustrar são os scripts do Google Analytics. Não é preciso que o DOM esteja pronto para que eles sejam executados.

`defer` deve ser usado para `scripts` que devem ser executados somente quando o documento estiver pronto. Para exemplificar, um script que manipula o evento de *click* em uma tag `<a>` no DOM.

E só para deixar mais claro que não é a mesma coisa.
Antes de `</body>`:

```
<script src='a.js'></script> <!-- será baixado e executado. -->
<script src='b.js'></script> <!-- será baixado depois de 'a.js' e executado. -->
<script src='c.js'></script> <!-- será baixado depois de 'b.js' e executado. -->
```

Já com `async`:

```
<!--
  Serão baixados todos ao mesmo tempo e executados após o download.
  Eles serão requisitados paralelamente e executados na sequência.
-->
<script async src='a.js'></script>
<script async src='b.js'></script>
<script async src='c.js'></script>
```

E com `defer`:

```
<!--
  Serão baixados todos ao mesmo tempo e executados somente quando a
  renderização do documento estiver concluída. Assim como o 'async',
  eles serão requisitados paralelamente e executados na sequência.
-->
<script defer src='a.js'></script>
<script defer src='b.js'></script>
<script defer src='c.js'></script>
```

> As bibliotecas para carregamento assíncrono, como o LABjs, ainda são
>   úteis, tendo em vista estes atributos(`async`/`defer`)? Ou eles são de
>   certa maneira mais seguros, garantindo o carregamento assíncrono
>   independendo da versão do navegador?

Aqui vai a questão de compatibilidade. Não conheço essas bibliotecas mas certamente elas tem como propósito (além do "carregamento assíncrono") suprir a incompatibilidade dos navegadores. Se você não quer ter surpresas com `async` e `defer`, use uma biblioteca que trate isso.
<sup>[Veja esse artigo no CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/)</sup>

> Considerando que o `defer` permite que o script seja carregado de
>   forma assíncrona, mas só permite sua execução após a renderização, ele
>   pode ser melhor que o `async`, já que este executa após o
>   carregamento, mesmo que ainda esteja ocorrendo a renderização?

Não vejo um sendo melhor que o outro pois não servem para a mesma coisa, embora ambos fazem o download do script sem interromper a renderização mas o modo como esses scripts serão executados funciona de forma diferente.

Scripts que utilizam atributo `async` e `defer` fazem uma diferença maior quando eles não estão localizados tão no final do documento. Como a análise do HTML ocorre da esquerda para direita, de cima para baixo, começando pelo o primeiro elemento declarado `<html>`, até quando ele seja fechado. Se algum script está localizado logo antes do elemento `</body>`, torna-se redundante o uso dos atributos `async` e `defer`.

Como a análise do documento já está quase completa naquele momento, esses elementos script não tem muito o que bloquear.

- [Asynchronous vs Deferred JavaScript](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/)

Comment: Sua resposta está bem mais correta que a minha (que acabei de excluir). Pelo que andei lendo, nenhum dos atributos determina como o script será *carregado*, somente o momento em que será *executado*. O "carregamento assíncrono" que se obtém com eles é um efeito colateral, já que eliminam a necessidade de bloquear imediatamente o processamento do documento para executar o script. Foi o que entendi da especificação e de outros artigos que li.

Comment: Boa resposta, coincidiu com o que li, ambos carregam de forma assíncrona, um executa após a renderização o outro após o carregamento.

Bom a ressalva que cada um tem seu propósito, se eu for executar um script que necessita que a renderização esteja completa para sim executa-lo, então usaria `defer`, ao invés de `async`.

Comment: Relacionada: [Ao usar **`async`** e **`defer`**, a ordem dos scripts é respeitada?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85413/4808).

Comment: Link quebrado do **Test drive demo: HTML5 async** a MS deve ter tirado do ar já.  :/