# Como funciona o attributo async do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, async

Eu estava lendo sobre o atributo `async`, que é utilizado na tag `<script>`, e fiquei curioso e duvidoso a respeito de algumas coisas.

De acordo com o [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp):

> A script that will be run asynchronously as soon as it is available

Traduzindo:

> Um script que será executado de forma assíncrona, assim que ele
>   estiver disponível

Tenho algumas perguntas a fazer a respeito dessa implementação:

1. Com a implementação do attributo `async`, devo agora parar de
   colocar alguns scripts no `<body>` da minha página (como no caso do jQuery UI, que é pesado), ou são coisas
   diferentes ?
2. Usá-lo pode implicar em algum problema de performasse ou definições das variáveis em um certo contexto (por exemplo,
   se eu usar no `jQuery`, ocorrer alguma "espera excessiva" para definir
   a variável `$` como referência ao  `jQuery`)?
3. O `assync` faz a mesma coisa (ou pelo menos faz parecido) que a
   definição de um `callback` em `window.onload`?
4. Qual é a principal vantagens em usá-la ?

Comment: Resumidamente, o script é baixado sem bloquear a renderização da página. Em seguida, é executado, mesmo que a página não tenha sido completamente carregada. Talvez [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46459/) ajude em alguns pontos.

Comment: Marquei como duplicata por considerar que a resposta da outra pergunta esclarece todas essas dúvidas.

Comment: tudo bem @bfavaretto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Creio que o que deve importar com o atributo `async` seja o uso de manipulação do DOM pelo JavaScript, que pode acabar criando mais problemas se os elementos não estiverem carregados quando o script precisar deles.
2. Sim. Se você vai usar um `$("input")` mas o input é gerado depois que a função chega a esse ponto, você vai ter problemas.
3. Não, o `async` executa o código no momento que ele é baixado por completo pelo navegador.
4. A principal vantagem seria para usuários de celulares, com execução mais rápida do JavaScript.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, @Mutley