# Ao usar async e defer, a ordem dos scripts é respeitada?

Tags: javascript, html5, assincronismo

Para um único script, a ordem de carga/execução na presença ou não dos atributos `async` e `defer` é clara: sem nada, carrega e executa imediatamente, com `async` carrega em paralelo e executa ao final da carga, com `defer` carrega em paralelo e executa ao final da renderização:

[image]

Minha dúvida é o que acontece quando há mais de um script na página, em especial se o uso ou não dos atributos acima for combinado:

```
<script src="A.js" defer></script> <!-- Grande -->
<script src="B.js" defer></script> <!-- Pequeno -->
<script src="C.js" async></script> <!-- Grande -->
<script src="D.js" async></script> <!-- Pequeno -->
<script src="E.js"></script>       <!-- Grande -->
<script src="F.js"></script>       <!-- Pequeno -->
```

Pelo meu entendimento, pode-se fazer algumas afirmações com certa segurança (corrijam-me se eu estiver enganado):

- E executará antes de F;
- A e B executarão depois de E e F;
- C e D podem executar antes ou depois de E e F (inclusive entre um e outro);
- D pode executar antes de C, se sua carga for mais rápida.

Mas para outras eu não sei a resposta:

- B pode executar antes de A, se sua carga for mais rápida? Ou o `defer` impõe uma ordem aos demais scripts também com `defer`?
- Se D for carregado enquanto E está carregando (mas não *executando*), ele executará antes de E ou não? (i.e. quando a carga de um script síncrono começou, é preciso esperar sua execução terminar para executar um script assíncrono?)
- C e D podem executar depois de A e B? Em outras palavras, se a carga de C por exemplo demorar demais, e tanto a renderização da página quanto a carga de A e B concluírem primeiro, estes podem executar imediatamente, ou é necessário que todos os scripts `async` executem antes que qualquer script `defer` execute?

Gostaria de saber se possível o que está especificado em relação à ordem de execução dos scripts e o que pode variar com a implementação (sem necessidade de fazer testes, embora estes sejam bem-vindos como complemento).

Comment: possível duplicata de [Sobre o atributo booleano defer e async vs otimização](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46459/sobre-o-atributo-booleano-defer-e-async-vs-otimiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: da uma lida aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46475/12032

Comment: Na [resposta do re22](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46475/14674) diz que não tem como saber a execução dos _defers_. Mas [aqui](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/) entendi que é por ordem de ocorrência.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Já tinha lido essa resposta, mas não esclareceu todas as minhas dúvidas. Talvez algumas de suas referências externas respondam, mas senti falta de uma resposta mais direta no que diz respeito à ordem, daí a pergunta. Além disso, li algumas referências conflitantes (ex.: [esse site](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html) diz que "If the script relies upon or is relied upon by another script then use defer", mas isso contradiz a resposta linkada, que diz "não tem como saber em que ordem eles serão executados"; qual está certo? Etc).

Comment: até onde li, o meu inglês é bem +- então posso estar enganado, defer "era" para garantir a ordem dos scripts pós load da pagina mas na pratica é que ele não garante http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work

Comment: Na prática recomenda-se compactar tudo num script só, tanto para diminuir latência quanto para evitar estas "questões de ordem". Aí você pode usar defer e async ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @epx Claro, mas ainda que essa solução "tamanho único" cubra 95% dos casos, ela está longe de ser perfeita. Como já comentei [nessa outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1112/215), onde você coloca o script tem impacto na experiência do usuário (ex.: esperar mais e ver um conteúdo "bonito", ou ver um conteúdo "cru" mais rápido e inesperadamente vê-lo mudar em resposta ao script, caso só CSS não bastar), além de que unificar complica o uso de CDNs. Conhecer mais a fundo sobre o assunto nos dá mais ferramentas para nos aproximarmos mais do resultado ideal para cada caso particular.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Como ninguém respondeu, fiz umas pesquisas, uns testes, e dei uma auto-resposta. De fato, no HTML 4 a ordem dos `defer`s não era especificada, e os *browsers* podiam executá-los na ordem que eles quisessem (como a resposta que você linkou - de 2011 - também afirma). Já o HTML5 impõe sim uma ordem, e os *browsers* modernos aparentemente a respeitam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR - `async` executa a qualquer momento e em qualquer ordem, `defer` e "normal" executam na ordem que são declarados (mas todos os `defer` após todos os "normais").

Encontrar uma especificação precisa do comportamento de `async` e `defer` é complicado, uma vez que os mesmos têm influência em diversas etapas do processamento do *browser*. Segundo [a especificação do HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element):

> **Nota:** Os detalhes de processamento exatos para esses atributos são, principalmente por razões históricas, de certo modo não triviais, envolvendo um número de aspectos do HTML. Os requisitos de implementação são portanto por necessidade espalhados pela especificação. Os algoritmos baixo (nesta seção) descrevem o núcleo desse processamento, mas estes algoritmos referenciam e são referenciados pelas regras de *parsing* para as tags [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) de [início](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#scriptTag) e [fim](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#scriptEndTag) no HTML, em [conteúdo estrangeiro](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#scriptForeignEndTag), e [em XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#scriptTagXML), as regras para o método [`document.write()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-document-write), o manuseio do processo de [*scripting*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#scripting), etc.

Alguns dos pontos da pergunta são respondíveis pela especificação, entretanto:

### B pode executar antes de A, se sua carga for mais rápida? Ou o `defer` impõe uma ordem aos demais scripts também com `defer`?

Não, a ordem é respeitada. Segundo essa mesma especificação, há uma lista de scripts a serem executados quando o documento terminar o *parsing*, e cada script com `defer` deve ser incluído **no final dessa lista**:

> To **prepare a script**, the user agent must act as follows:
>
> 15. Then, the first of the following options that describes the situation must be followed:
>
>     - **If the element has a [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute, and the element has a [`defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer) attribute, and the element has been flagged as ["parser-inserted"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#parser-inserted), and the element does not have an [`async`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) attribute**
>
>       The element must be added to the end of the **list of scripts that will execute when the document has finished parsing** associated with the [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) of the parser that created the element.

Dessa forma, se um *browser* age em conformidade com essa especificação (ver testes abaixo) e executa os scripts na ordem que eles foram inseridos nessa lista (i.e. a ordem na qual aparece no código-fonte) então se eu carrego, digamos, o jQuery de um CDN, o Bootstrap de outro, e meu próprio código do meu servidor, todos com `defer`, eles devem executar nessa mesma ordem, de modo que a dependência de um a outro deve ser satisfeita.

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="/js/meucodigo.min.js" defer></script>
```

**Mas atenção:** Se o *browser* não dá suporte adequado a HTML5, os scripts `defer` *podem sim* executar fora de ordem! Segundo a [especificação do HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer), o `defer` é apenas uma "dica" ao *browser* de que o script não vai produzir nenhum conteúdo ao documento (por ex.: via `document.write`) e portanto ele pode continuar fazendo o *parse* e renderizando. Nada mais é especificado, então é seguro assumir que a ordem de execução pode variar de implementação pra implementação.

### Se D for carregado enquanto E está carregando (mas não executando), ele executará antes de E ou não?

*Acho* que sim. A especificação aplicável aos elementos com `async` (mesmo item 15 acima) diz o seguinte:

> The [task](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#concept-task) that the [networking task source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#networking-task-source) places on the task queue once the [fetching algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#fetch) has completed must [execute the script block](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#execute-the-script-block) and then remove the element from the [set of scripts that will execute as soon as possible](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#set-of-scripts-that-will-execute-as-soon-as-possible).

Em contraste, os elementos **sem** `async` possuem um comportamento diferente:

> The element is the [pending parsing-blocking script](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#pending-parsing-blocking-script) of the [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) of the parser that created the element. (There can only be one such script per [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) at a time.)
>
> The [task](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#concept-task) that the [networking task source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#networking-task-source) places on the task queue once the [fetching algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#fetch) has completed must set the element's ["ready to be parser-executed"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#ready-to-be-parser-executed) flag. The parser will handle executing the script.

Ou seja, quando o *browser* encontra um ou mais scripts com `async` (ex.: C e D), ele os coloca na fila de tarefas e segue adiante. Quando ele encontra um *sem* `async` (nem `defer`) ele também o coloca na fila de tarefas, mas o marca como "bloqueador de *parsing*". Não entendi muito bem o que isso significa (pois o processo de *parsing* em geral está descrito em outro documento - não tenho certeza qual), mas na prática deve servir pra interromper a renderização (mas não necessariamente a carga) até que o script tenha acabado de executar.

Entretanto, não está claro se a presença de um script "bloqueador de *parsing*" é ou não empecilho para que a tarefa de conclusão dos scripts `async` ("executar o bloco de script") seja executada nesse estado. Na dúvida, vou adotar uma postura conservadora e assumir que "não" (i.e. vou trabalhar com a hipótese de que após a carga de E começar - mas antes de sua execução - C e D talvez possam executar).

Os testes abaixo parecem corroborar essa minha interpretação.

### C e D podem executar depois de A e B? (...) ou é necessário que todos os scripts async executem antes que qualquer script defer execute?

Sim, podem executar a qualquer momento. Não encontrei nada na especificação que proibisse scripts na lista de "scripts a serem executados assim que possível" de executarem depois de scripts na lista de "scripts a serem executados quando o documento terminar o *parsing*". De fato, um simples teste no Chrome (sem *webserver*, no próprio sistema de arquivos) chegou à ordem "C,E,F,A,B,D" em um dos testes, e "E,F,A,B,C,D" em outros.

## Testes

Para testar o comportamento real dos *browsers*, fiz uma pequena alteração no [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) do Python:

```python
import SimpleHTTPServer, SocketServer, sys, time
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class MeuHTTPServer(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(*args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(int(sys.argv[2]))
        return SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(*args, **kwargs)
        
SocketServer.TCPServer(("", int(sys.argv[1])), MeuHTTPServer).serve_forever()
```

E abri o programa 7 vezes, um para servir cada arquivo (os 6 scripts e o html em si). Os scripts "grandes" (A,C,E) aguardam 5 segundos antes de retornar, os "pequenos" (B,D,F), 1 segundo. O html usado foi:

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://localhost:8001/a.js" defer></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8002/b.js" defer></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8003/c.js" async></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8004/d.js" async></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8005/e.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8006/f.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

E cada script simplesmente faz um `console.log` para "se identificar". Os resultados (no Windows 7) foram:

- **Firefox:** "D,E,F,A,B,C", demonstrando todos os pontos citados (inclusive, a requisição `GET` de **todos** os scripts foi feita *antes* do `d` executar - confirmando que um script `async` pode executar enquanto um "normal" está carregando). Em outro teste, "D,C,E,F,A,B" (também consistente com o resto da resposta). Depois disso, "C,D,E,F,A,B" após os scripts entrarem na cache.
- **Chrome:** "D,C,E,F,A,B" em 2 testes, "E,F,A,B,C,D" após os scripts entrarem na cache (notei uma tendência dos scripts `async` serem executados *por último* - mesmo após os `defer` - diferentemente do Firefox, que tende a executá-los na ordem).
- **Internet Explorer 11:** "D,E,C,F,A,B" (demonstrando que um script `async` de fato pode executar entre dois "normais") na primeira vez, "D,C,E,F,A,B" nas seguintes (aparentemente o IE não coloca recursos vindos do `localhost` em cache nunca).
- **Opera e Safari:** "D,C,E,F,A,B" em 1 teste, "E,F,A,B,C,D" nos demais (mesmo que o Chrome).

Minha conclusão é que a interpretação que dei à especificação está correta, e os principais *browsers* estão em conformidade com essa especificação.