# Erro em incluir arquivo .js em tema wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Incluí um arquivo .js no header.php do meu tema usando o painel de controle do wordpress.

Porém, a linha que inseri no arquivo não aparece na página quando eu verifico o código fonte.

Estou fazendo assim:

Painel Wordpress > Aparência > Editor > header.php >

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/contato/municipios.js"></script>`

Porém, é como se eu não tivesse feito nada...

Incluí a linha acima entre as tags head.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma dica?

Comment: Dê uma olhada se o site não esta com algum plugin de cache :|

Comment: @FelipedeFarias não consegui identificar nenhum plugin de cache. abri a pasta de temas, e inclui o código direto no arquivo header, mesmo assim, quando acesso a página, a linha nao é exibida...

Comment: Você pode passar o site?

Comment: @FelipedeFarias https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/regioes/ vou add na postagem um print de como eu fiz

Comment: Será que teu wordpress esta usando supercache? (é um plugin para wordpress)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento achei um plugin chamado WP Rocket, ele é de cache. Fiz a limpeza e ao verificar o código do site, o arquivo aparece, mas um pouco diferente do que eu progamei, dá uma olhada por favor: https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/regioes

Comment: @FelipedeFarias achei um plugin chamado WP Rocket, ele é de cache. Fiz a limpeza e ao verificar o código do site, o arquivo aparece, mas um pouco diferente do que eu progamei, dá uma olhada por favor: protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/regioes

Comment: Acho que é por causa do proprio Rocket, para otimizar tudo ele parece mesclar todos .js em um unico, veja na primeira linha `<script src="https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/wp-content/plugins/wp-rocket/min/?f=/contato/municipios.js,/contato/municipios.js,/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js,...`, isso provavelmente ocorre automaticamente, mesmo que você não queira, a vantagem de mesclar tudo em uma coisa só é que irá só fazer um download e provavelmente será mais rápido que separados.

Comment: O problema de não estar funcionando é que tem scripts no seu site em ordem errada, jQuery sempre tem que ser o primeiro script, logo você tem que ajustar a ordem de tudo para que pare de ocorrer o erro: `TypeError: $ is not a function`, fora que tem JavaSCript no meio da sua página, fora de documento .js, e como todos seus scripts executam com `defer` isso vai falhar.

Comment: Sobre o defer e async leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304137/3635 - A solução é remover os javascript que estão soltos, como este `<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxRevslider;` e colocar em documentos com defer também, e também não esqueça que tem problemas na ordem dos seus documentos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio eu que o "problema" esta parcialmente no uso do Rocket (https://wp-rocket.me), que é um plugin para cache e otimização dos scripts injetados na página

Como pode ler nos "feautures" deles:

- https://wp-rocket.me/features/#feature-minification-concatenation ele concatenam os scripts injetados e minificam a página
- https://wp-rocket.me/features/#feature-defer-js-loading coloca todos scripts para carregar como `defer`

Ou seja por causa do `defer` só vai ser processado quando a página carregar, mas no meio do teu site tem scripts soltos, como este na linha 29 e 30:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxRevslider;

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                // CUSTOM AJAX CONTENT LOADING FUNCTION
```

Como o Rocket só consegue otimizar scripts que estejam em arquivos `.js`, então este script solto não será otimizado e devido ao uso de `defer` o script nem será processado, ou seja seria melhor se este script fosse movido para um arquivo `.js`

---

Então pra concluir, é por isto que mesmo ao escrever isto:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/contato/municipios.js"></script>
```

Você visualiza isto:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/wp-content/cache/busting/1/wp-includes-js-jquery-jquery-1.12.4.js'></script>

<script src="//use.typekit.net/e590690a5a7eb8cf5aba4f1e0fc6a9be49cb81a2.js" defer></script>

<script src="https://protegex.italorodrigo.com.br/wp-content/plugins/wp-rocket/min/?f=/contato/municipios.js,/contato/municipios.js,/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js,/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js,/wp-content/plugins/mega-addons-for-visual-composer/js/script.js,/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/public/assets/js/lightbox.js,/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js,/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js,/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js,/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/vendors/woocommerce-add-to-cart.js,/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-rotator/js/jquery.cycletwo.js,/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-rotator/js/jquery.cycletwo.addons.js,/wp-content/themes/easyweb/js/jquery.plugins.js" data-minify="1" defer></script>
```

Outra coisa, provavelmente o `municipios.js` deveria ser o ultimo, depois dos add-ons e plugins jQuery, se o tal municipios.js depender de jQuery, é claro.

---

### Leia sobre defer e async

- [Atributo Async e Defer Javascript - Async pausa renderização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304137/3635)
- [Ao usar async e defer, a ordem dos scripts é respeitada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85413/3635)