# Erro (Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined) no "Run" na API do MAPS para o Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, algoritmo-de-busca, google-maps-api-3

Está ocorrendo um erro no "**google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)**;" e não consigo resolver :'(

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    scrollwheel: false
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  // Create the autocomplete helper, and associate it with
  // an HTML text input box.
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Get the full place details when the user selects a place from the
  // list of suggestions.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace(/** @type {!google.maps.Place} */ ({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    }));
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
        'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
        place.formatted_address + '</div>');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

// Run the initialize function when the window has finished loading.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Por favor, descreva melhor seu problema e qual o erro.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Precisa carregar o plugin da API:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=CHAVE_DA_API">
</script>
```

Como você está iniciando o plugin via código em:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Então **não** deve especificar `async defer` na tag `script` (**[veja informações sobre `async` e `defer` nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46475/8063)**), ficando somente:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=CHAVE_DA_API"></script>
```

Ou então você pode iniciar o plugin via *callback* na URL (aí sim é necessário o `async` e `defer`):

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=CHAVE_DA_API&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

Então neste último caso, terá que apagar a linha `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` que tem o mesmo efeito do *callback*.