# Atributo Async e Defer Javascript - Async pausa renderização?

Tags: javascript, async, defer

Estava a ler novamente, sobre async e defer.
Percebi que o Async, apesar de carregar o script de forma assincrona, após o carregamento, o HTML é pausado para execução do Script.

o Defer funcionaria como um Async, porém a execução do Script é feita após a renderização do HTML.

Isso confirma?

E se confirmado, não havendo fatores complicantes, usar defer no lugar do async promove páginas mais rápidas, ou melhor, com visualização mais rápida?

Comment: O `Defer` serve para indicar que determinado *script* **deve** ser carregado antes do evento `DOMContentLoaded`, porém ele irá baixar na ordem (enquanto o *script* `A.js` não for baixado/executado, o navegador não irá baixar/executar o *script* `B.js`). Já o `Async` serve para indicar ao navegador que ele pode continuar baixando e executando outros *scripts* independentes, ou seja, o navegador irá baixar e executar sem seguir a ordel (1º `A.js`, 2º `C.js`, 3º `E.js` etc). E não, o `defer` — sozinho — não tem um impacto grande no carregamento da página, mas ambos (depende dos fatores) sim.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr você diz que "enquanto script A.js não for baixado/executado, o navegador não irá baixar/executar  o script B.js... Porém, eu li um artigo, e entendi que apenas na EXECUÇÃO ele fará na ordem e não assincrono, mas para dar o fetch/baixar ele fará de forma assincrona.

Comment: https://braziljs.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/exec-defer-multiple.png

Comment: 5 scripts, .js com atributo defer, são baixados de forma assincrona, e executados de forma sincrona(dessa vez, sem atrapalhar a renderização do conteúdo, como o "async" atrapalharia).

Comment: Estou errado? Então, seguindo essa lógica, para evitar a pausa na renderização, o defer seria o mais indicado, se pude-se ser usado?

Comment: Sobre o *download* estás correto. Olhei no W3 (https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/script.html) para confirmar, estava com dúvida entre um e outro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O HTML não é necessariamente "pausado", na verdade o que deve estar ocorrendo é que alguma execução de script que esta manipulando o DOM de suas páginas, logo não é necessariamente o `async` que pausou algo.

O `async` faz **"o download"** ocorrer sem parar o processo de renderização, ou seja não tem haver com a execução do script, mas sim com o download, logo depois do download a execução de uma rotina especifica pode sim afetar algo, depende muito do que fez.

O `defer` é semelhante ao evento `DOMContentLoaded`, exemplo:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   ....
});
```

Ou semelhante ao `$(document).ready()` do jQuery, como eu disse são semelhantes apenas e só, o atributo `defer` é usado apenas para scripts externos e vale notar também que ele será executado antes do evento `DOMContentLoaded`.

---

Quando `async` é omitido ou é `false` o script terá que baixar e executar antes (a partir do ponto aonde foi injetado na página), por exemplo:

```
 <p>foo</p>
 <script src="foo.js"></script>
 <p>bar</p>
```

Neste caso `<p>foo</p>` seria renderizado e `<p>bar</p>` não, neste caso abaixo:

```
 <head>
 <script src="foo.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 ...
```

O `<body>` só seria renderizado depois de foo.js ser baixado e executado.

Essa resposta do @Renan já dá uma boa margem de entendimento (inclusive sua pergunta):

- [Sobre o atributo booleano defer e async vs otimização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46475/3635)

Creio eu que com isto tudo o que você deseja resolver é o bloqueio de renderização (blocking-render), logo isso deve ser um problema especifico, vou explicar um detalhe, é provavelmente que você tenha scripts em série assim:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script src="bar.js"></script>
<script src="baz.js"></script>
```

Neste caso o jquery.js é baixado e executado, então só depois disto o download de foo.js começara, o mesmo vale para bar.js e baz.js, que precisam esperar os anteriores serem baixados e carregados na ordem que estão, no entanto se fizer isso:

```
<script async src="jquery.js"></script>
<script async src="foo.js"></script>
<script async src="bar.js"></script>
<script async src="baz.js"></script>
```

Todos serão baixado quase ao mesmo tempo, o que irá diferenciar é o peso e a concorrencia, que poderá variar qual será baixado antes, supondo que todos dependam do jQuery.js, se eles forem baixados primeiro e o jquery só depois todos irão falhar, então não basta apenas colocar async para vencer o bloqueio de renderização e acabar quebrando o site, por isto mesmo formulei esta resposta com uma sugestão de como fazer download assincrono e conseguir preservar a ordem:

- [Utilizar async=“” irá resultar em um carregamento síncrono ou assíncrono?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231983/3635)

Note que `defer` respeita a ordem de execução e download, mas ele só é iniciado após a página HTML ter sido baixada por completo e ter sido renderizada, mas também é preciso notar que você pode usar defer e async combinados que irá ter o comportamento de ambos combinado:

> Carregarão assincronamente na ordem que forem baixados e executados, mas só após o HTML ter sido renderizado por completo

---

### CSS e o bloqueio de renderização [extra]

Como expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115240/3635 o CSS também afetar causando o bloqueio de renderização, mas ele não tem um atributo `async` para resolver, o que você poderia experimentar é usar o evento `onload` para só processar o CSS quando ele estivesse devidamente carregado:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"></noscript>
```

Ou até mesmo só carregar ele via JavaScript, por exemplo:

```
function loadCss(css) {
    var added = false;

    function trigger()
    {
        if (added) return;

        added = true;

        var css = document.createElement("link");

        css.onload = function() {
            document.body.appendChild(css);
        };

        css.rel = "stylesheet";
        css.src = css;
    }

    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
        trigger();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", trigger);
    }
}

loadCss("css/seu_css.css");
loadCss("css/seu_outro_css.css");
```

Comment: Que resposta completa pra caramba.. Hahaha, obrigado