# appendChild não está funcionado

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando passar os elementos do array com for( of ) para os elementos de html que eu criei pelo js. O problema é q quando tento colocar o  criado no js dentro do, usando appendChild,o código da erro.

Esse é o **javascript:**

```
var listElement = document.querySelector('#app ul');
var inputElement = document.querySelector('#app input');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('#app button');

var todos = [
    'Fazer café',
    'Estudar Javascript',
    'Lavar a Louça'
];

function renderTodos(){

for(todo of todos){
    var todoElement = document.createElement('li');
    var todoText = document.createTextNode(todo);

    todoElement.appendChild(todoText);
    listElement.appendChild(todoElement);
   }
}

renderTodos();
```

Esse é o **html;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content Language" content="pt-br">
<title>Parte 3</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>    

       </ul>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Digite um To do">
       <button>Adicionar</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Erro ocorrido:

> script.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of
>   null at renderTodos (script.js:18) at script.js:22

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro? Copiei o código no JSFiddle funcionou normalmente.

Comment: script.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at renderTodos (script.js:18)
    at script.js:22

Comment: Seu script deve estar rodando antes do DOM estar pronto, então a **<ul>** ainda não existe, coloque o script depois da tag **</body>**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É a ordem da sua execução, você tem que usar ou `DOMContentLoaded` ou o atributo `defer` na tag `<script>`, isto porque você esta executando o script antes dos elementos no body terem sido baixados ou renderizados.

> Aproveite e leia isto:
>
> - [Atributo Async e Defer Javascript - Async pausa renderização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304137/3635)

Pode usar `DOMContentLoaded` para checar se o DOM já carregou:

```
var listElement = document.querySelector('#app ul');
var inputElement = document.querySelector('#app input');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('#app button');

var todos = [
    'Fazer café',
    'Estudar Javascript',
    'Lavar a Louça'
];

function renderTodos(){

for(todo of todos){
    var todoElement = document.createElement('li');
    var todoText = document.createTextNode(todo);

    todoElement.appendChild(todoText);
    listElement.appendChild(todoElement);
   }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", renderTodos);
```

---

Ou usar `defer` para que o script seja executado somente após o DOM estar pronto:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```

---

Outra maneira seria simplesmente tirar o script do head e colocar no final do body, assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content Language" content="pt-br">
<title>Parte 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>    

       </ul>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Digite um To do">
       <button>Adicionar</button>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

> Não é necessário usar `defer` ao mesmo tempo que `DOMContentLoaded`, apesar que ambos tem uma pequena diferença na hora/tempo que irão executar, mas ainda sim ambos serão após o DOM estar acessivel as funções como `querySeletor`, `getElementById`, etc

Comment: Vlw, funcionou. Vou cometer muito ainda esse tipo de erro, sou iniciante.